# On Android 12+, how do I disable mobile internet without disabling MMS?

Tags: mobile-data, shell, android-12, apn, android-13

My good old phone from 2013 is dying. I have been satisfied with it, but even if it was still sold nowadays, I would not buy more of the same since it’s becoming increasingly difficult to not have either an iOS or an Android phone. I don’t want iOS for reasons not pertaining to my question, so Android remains, however, constant internet access is blocking me.

There are a few reasons to disable mobile internet on one’s phone, but I’m not here to discuss these. I just want to be able to disable mobile internet.

There are tons of sites giving tutorials on how to do this, but as far as I’ve seen, none gives a correct reply, because :

1. Either they provide steps on how to disable mobile data, which indeed disables mobile internet, but MMS too in the process
2. Or give a per-app solution, which won’t really completely block all mobile internet traffic, let’s be honest

A few years ago, someone with a Huawei phone asked me for help on this very subject, and I was indeed able to help him, by defining explicitly which APN was for what, keeping only the MMS role for the MMS-only APN and removing everything else. And it worked.

But things may have changed, and I certainly don’t want to buy a phone only to find it’s now impossible. If it’s become impossible indeed, then well, despite the drawbacks I will definitely get an oldie.

**So, more concisely :**

- How can I disable mobile internet ?
- Not per-app, system-wide
- MMS shall remain enabled
- Android 12+ (I suppose that’s what all new phones are running nowadays)
- I’m not afraid of using `adb` and going through a shell
- No third party programs
- Jailbreaking/rooting is a big no no, if I have to fight against the phone vendor, then I better buy somewhere else
- Which brands leave it possible ?
- Which brands block it ?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200967517

Comment: @beeshyams That seems to describe a problem with a strange feature that brings all mobile data on, including internet, when sending an MMS… that’s a really weird a dirty way of doing things… but if it’s still possible to define types for APNs as I did in the past, then there’s another way around

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have an Android 13 phone, I can confirm it’s indeed possible (tested with a Samsung Galaxy A04s).

In the Android system, each APN has a defined *APN type*, which is a comma-separated list of roles attributed to the APN. [An exhaustive list of roles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/data/ApnSetting#constants) can be found on Android’s site for developers. In the constants list, all the ones beginning with `TYPE_`. As of today, the list of accepted roles is : `bip`, `cbs`, `default`, `dun`, `emergency`, `enterprise`, `fota`, `hipri`, `ia`, `ims`, `mcx`, `mms`, `supl`, `vsim`, `xcap`.

The `default` role is special : it gives the APN roles that have not been given explicitly to other APNs.

The method is simple : keep the `mms` role for the MMS APN, remove everything else. If you have more than one APN, either delete the others if possible, or give them a restricted role such as `emergency`. An APN with zero roles defined seems to behave as having the `default` role.

**WARNING :** Some providers may depend on mobile data to provide emergency services, changing the roles may block or degrade such services. If there’s only one APN with the `default` role, replacing it with `emergency` may be a good choice, but it’s not 100% impossible that emergency services rely on other roles as well. One can’t foresee what all mobile operators do, be it good or bad.

More precisely :

1. In the parameters, go to the list of configured APNs : Connections => Mobile networks => Access point names
2. For each APN, check the access point type, remove all roles except `mms`
3. Remove APNs with no MMS roles, or alternatively, set their role to `emergency`
4. To restore the defaults, on the APN list screen, tap the vertical ellipsis button ⋮ on the top right and choose the appropriate menu option
5. System updates are likely to reset custom APN configuration

In my case I had two APNs, APN A with only the `mms` role, and APN B with `default` and `mms` roles. I left APN A untouched, and set APN B to `emergency` only. This made APN B disappear from the list but it’s still there, just hidden from the UI. Resetting APN configuration still works and brings back both APNs with their default settings.